# LSF job submission - stdout & stderr redirection

Tags: lsf

I've submitted my job by the following command:

```
bsub -e error.log -o output.log ./myScript.sh
```

I have a question: why are the output and errors logs available only once the job ended?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LSF doesn't steam the output back to the submission host. If the submission host and the execution host have a shared file system, and the JOB_SPOOL_DIR is in that shared file system (the spool directory is $HOME/.lsbatch by default) then you should see the stdout and stderr there. After the job finishes, the files there are copied back to the location specified by bsub.

Check `bparams -a | grep JOB_SPOOL_DIR` to see if the admin has changed the location of the spool dir.  With or without the -o/-e options, while the job is running its stdout/err will be captured in the job's spool directory.  When the job is finished, the stdout/stderr is copied to the filenames specified by bsub -o/-e.  The location of the files in the spool dir is `$JOB_SPOOL_DIR/<jobsubmittime>.<jobid>.out` or `$JOB_SPOOL_DIR/<jobsubmittime>.<jobid>.err`

```
[user1@beta ~]$ cat log.sh 
LINE=1
while :
do
  echo "line $LINE"
  LINE=$((LINE+1))
  sleep 1
done

[user1@beta ~]$ bsub -o output.log -e error.log ./log.sh
Job <930> is submitted to default queue <normal>.
[user1@beta ~]$ tail -f .lsbatch/*.930.out
line 1
line 2
line 3
...
```

Comment: The submission host and the execution host have a shared file system, but I have no stderr and stdout in $HOME/.lsbach.

Comment: Hi @Fab. I added some more information to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [LSF documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_config_ref/lsf.conf.lsb_stdout_direct.5.html) the behaviour is configurable:

> If LSB_STDOUT_DIRECT is not set and you use the bsub -o option, the standard output of a job is written to a temporary file and copied to the file you specify after the job finishes.